# searching for german characters with sql using LIKE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, special-characters, sql-like

I'm working with a database where german names are used, i.e. `Fürst`. Now I built a HTML-Form with a searchfield. Used `htmlentities` and some tests to verified no "bad stuff" are entered and then `html_entity_decode` before the query. A simple query would then looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE firstname LIKE "%fü%" OR lastname LIKE "%fü%"
```

However, this find not only `Fürst`, but `Furt`as well. How can I fix this? The database and the tables are in `utf8_unicode_ci` and have to stay that way.

Comment: Add a collate clause to the comparison, something like `WHERE firstname collate german_ci like...`.

Comment: can you be more specific? theres no `german_ci`. when I use `latin1_german2_ci`, it says: `#1253 - COLLATION 'latin1_german2_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'`. When I try `utf8_unicode_ci`, I get the same result as in the original post

Comment: I don't know your dbms product's collation names. Perhaps you should tag the dbms you're using, and you'll get an answer that suits you.

Comment: the server is running with phpmyadmin 4.5.2 with 10.1.9-MariaDB on debian8.3. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the [collations for each charset](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/supported-character-sets-and-collations/)

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE firstname LIKE "%fü%" COLLATE utf8mb4_german2_ci            
                          OR lastname LIKE "%fü%" COLLATE utf8mb4_german2_ci
```

utf8mb4_unicode_ci would probably work as well.

Comment: 1. how do you come up with utf8_bin? 2. its not working "#1253 - COLLATION 'latin1_german2_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'"

Comment: @yangsunny I thought you said tables are in utf8_unicode_ci .For utf8_unicode_ci  this is valid.And that message error doesnt seem to refer to this query.Where do you get latin1_german2_ci from?

Comment: sry, I mean of course "#1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'". and the database is in utf8_unicode_ci, for sure.

Comment: @yangsunny Ok but in Maria db the lowest level charset has priority, column collation overrides table collation which overrides database collation etc.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a simple comment.)

`COLLATION` names start with the `CHARACTER SET` name.  This thread has mentioned `utf8`, `utf8mb4`, and `latin1` `CHARACTER SETs`.  You *must* use a `COLLATION` for the given `CHARACTER SET`.

*First* pick a `CHARACTER SET`.  `utf8`, `utf8mb4`, and `latin1` all handle German.  But if you expect to handle other languages, consider:

- `latin` is limited to Western European languages.  It cannot, for example, handle Greek.  (latin1 needs 1 byte per character.)
- `utf8mb4` covers all known languages, with room for more.  (up to 4 bytes per character)  This `CHARACTER SET` was not available until version 5.5.3.
- `utf8` is a subset of `utf8mb4`, leaving out a few Chinese characters and the newer Emoji.  (up to 3 bytes per character)

`CHARACTER SET` provides the byte-encoding for the characters.  `COLLATION` says how two strings compare, such whether `ss` and `ß` should be treated as equal.

*After* picking the `CHARACTER SET`, pick the `COLLATION`.  Or let id 'default':  `latin1_swedish_ci` / `utf8_general_ci` / `utf8mb4_general_ci`.  These defaults are kinda good for multi-lingual use; but that is debatable.  `ss` != `ß` in all those defaults.

Going forward, the "best" solution is `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` for overall multilingual data.

If you are focused on just German, then you *may* want to consider `..._german2_ci` collations.  For example:

```
utf8_german2_ci     A=a=ª=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą     < ae=Ä=Æ=ä=æ < az < B
utf8_unicode_520_ci A=a=ª=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą < ae=Æ=æ     < az < B
utf8_unicode_ci     A=a=ª=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą < ae         < az < Æ=æ < B
utf8_general_ci     A=a=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą   < Z < Æ=æ
```

(Ditto for `utf8mb4_...` collations.)

So, if you really care how `æ` compares, you need to be picky about the collation.  (utf8 and utf8mb4 act the same.)  [More collation comparisions](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html).

`ue=Ü=ü` for `..._german2_ci` collations, but probably no others.  The others (mostly) treat `U=u=Ü=ü`, and leave `ue` to compare as two letters.

Comment: At the weekend, I came up with a solution using `COLLATE latin1_german2_ci`  for the columns in the table and `Default CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci` for the table itself. This would solve my problem, but I have no idea if it is ok to choose different collations for column and table or it is just a dirty&quick solution...

Comment: My database will only contain german, meaning I have to differ A from Ä. And I need to get data out of the database and display this in HTML as well. When I used latin1_german2_ci(its the charset/collation set before), I had to do some utf8_encode/decode. To save me this, I guess my options will be utf8_german2_ci or utf8mb4_german2_ci. Thank you very much for the very nice and detailed explanation about CHARACTER SET and COLLATION.

Comment: I converted all my tables and columns in utf8_german2_ci now. As you mentioned, in this collation, `A=a < ae=Ä=ä` which should means if I search for `ae`, `ä` should be found, right? However, it doesn't... why?

Comment: Grrrr...  I knew that `REGEXP` was inadequate in this area, but I thought `LIKE` was OK.  `SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_german2_ci;  select 'ue' = 'ü', 'ue' LIKE 'ü', 'ü' LIKE 'ue';`  --> 1,0,0.  So, what I said about how they compare does not fully transfer into `LIKE`.  Consider filing a bug with http://bugs.mysql.com against `LIKE` and collations.